# Action Detection on dynamically created component

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am creating a dynamically created component in angular 4 as shown below.

```
    import {
  Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc;
  name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;

  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
              private _injector: Injector,
              private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const tmpCmp = Component({
        moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: './e.component.html'})(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      })
  }
}
```

I want to trigger an action from the template url as shown below:Where and how do I handle this click event.
**e.component.html**

```
<div>
  <button  (click)="action()"></button>
  <h1 (click)="action()">Phrase</h1>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create method in your dynamic component class.

```
const tmpCmp = Component({moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: './e.component.html'})(class {

                 action(){
                     console.log('Action button clicked');
                 }

               });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,Ashwani for your help. Can you also tell me how can I access a parent variable inside this child component.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can simply achieve this by adding variable in this calls.

```
const tmpCmp = Component({moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: './e.component.html'})(class {

             componentVar = this.parentComponentVar; // or simpleVar passed in function.
             action(){
                 console.log('Action button clicked');
             }

           })
```

Please let me know if it work, otherwise I will create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Gr8, I’m happy to help